# How to update the prices in the stock API doesn't update

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, stock

I'm trying to get stocks prices from an API using python, but the thing is that when I put it in a while loop, it doesn't update, while the price is updating in the api, other thing, is there anyway to make the loop each 5 minutes? Here's the code:

```py
import urllib.request
import json


urlprices = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote-short/AMZN?apikey=555555555555555555"

obj = urllib.request.urlopen(urlprices)

data = json.load(obj)

a = 0

while a == 0:
    
    print(float(data[0]['price']))
```

[image]

Comment: *why* would it change? your code only makes one API call

Comment: You never update the data - you just print the same thing over and over again.

Comment: So it's not possible?

Comment: Yeah, I know, that's why I'm asking if it's possible

Comment: You could sleep for 5 minutes in the loop, and then do the update.

Comment: In any case, can you [edit] to clarify the question? The title and question body both ask *why* it doesn't update, and based on the comments it seems like you already know why it doesn't, you're actually asking *how* to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but you need to update your data within the while loop:

```
import urllib.request
import json
import time


a = 0

while a == 0:
    urlprices = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote-short/AMZN?apikey=555555555555555555"

    obj = urllib.request.urlopen(urlprices)

    data = json.load(obj)
    print(float(data[0]['price']))
    # here you should add a pause so that the loop will not hit the request limit for the api
    time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: You guys are amazing! It worked, thanks to both of you, I'll mark the answer as correct in 3 minutes